# How can I tell if my columns are R1C1 reference style with excel vba?

Tags: vba, excel

**Overview**
I am making a keyboard shortcut that will allow me to easily switch back and forth from the standard column reference "A1" to R1C1  and then back again.

**Problem**
I have the code to change from the two reference styles but I want to make an if statement that can identify which style is currently being used.

**Code**

```
Sub ColoumnReference()        
    Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1
    Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1
End Sub
```

**Looking to add an If statement**

```
Sub ColoumnReference()    
    If R1C1 Then
       Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1    
    Else   
       Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1
    End If    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub ColoumnReference()    
    If Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1 Then
        Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1
    Else
        Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked I will mark your answer correct when it lets me